# Scopes, timer and loop in a javascript object fired on scroll

Tags: javascript, timer, scopes

[Here](http://jsbin.com/reyasekega/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is the example.

I create an object that have 3 elements referenced by the first parameter (document.querySelectorAll...) the I loop through those elements and launch a specific scrolling function (simplified in the example. Inside this function I use [this approach](http://joshbroton.com/hooking-up-to-the-window-onscroll-event-without-killing-your-performance/) to detect the scroll and save perf. I pass the element every time I call this function (first commented console.log) and works well, then inside the timer also I still having the 3 elements (in this example) but then inside the if statement I only have the first one.

I think I understand the problem, but I'm not finding a solution.

```
function extend( a, b ) {
  for( var key in b ) { 
    if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
      a[key] = b[key];
    }
  }
  return a;
}

function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
    return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
    return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

function MyObject(el, opt){
  this.el = el;
  this.opt = extend( {}, this.opt );
  extend( this.opt, opt );
  this._init();
}

MyObject.prototype._init = function(){

  var self = this;
  //this.didScroll = false; //Remove this and put it per element

  this.totalObjs = document.querySelectorAll(this.el);
  this.objs = [].slice.call( this.totalObjs );

  this.objs.forEach( function( el, i ) {
    self._onScroll(el);
  });

};

MyObject.prototype._onScroll = function(e){

  var self = this;
  e.didScroll = false; // Add per element

  addEvent(window, 'scroll', function(){
    e.didScroll = true;
  });

  // Here I have my 3 elements
  // console.log(e.id);

  setInterval(function() {
    // Here I have my 3 elements
    // console.log(e.id);

    if( e.didScroll ){
      e.didScroll = false;

      // Here I have only the first element
      console.log(e.id);
    }
  }, 500);


};


var obj1 = new MyObject('.obj', {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your scope. You are setting an interval for each element but checking inside that interval from the main object and setting the `didScroll` variable to false on the first one. Set this variable on the element and it works just fine.

```
function extend( a, b ) {
  for( var key in b ) { 
    if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
      a[key] = b[key];
    }
  }
  return a;
}

function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
    return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
    return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

function MyObject(el, opt){
  this.el = el;
  this.opt = extend( {}, this.opt );
  extend( this.opt, opt );
  this._init();
}

MyObject.prototype._init = function(){

  var self = this;
  //this.didScroll = false; //Remove this and put it per element

  this.totalObjs = document.querySelectorAll(this.el);
  this.objs = [].slice.call( this.totalObjs );

  this.objs.forEach( function( el, i ) {
    self._onScroll(el);
  });

};

MyObject.prototype._onScroll = function(e){

  var self = this;
  e.didScroll = false; // Add per element

  addEvent(window, 'scroll', function(){
    e.didScroll = true;
  });

  // Here I have my 3 elements
  // console.log(e.id);

  setInterval(function() {
    // Here I have my 3 elements
    // console.log(e.id);

    if( e.didScroll ){
      e.didScroll = false;

      // Here I have only the first element
      console.log(e.id);
    }
  }, 500);


};


var obj1 = new MyObject('.obj', {});
```